# Bypassing the minimum size limit of a popup window in Chrome?

Tags: chrome

Recently I have come across several popup windows in chrome that somehow bypass the minimum height and width of a new window the browser usually imposes allowing them to hide mostly under the task bar, most have been crypto mining scripts but some have also been adverts that will just wait there for a while and then expand to full screen size. But I'm not so fussed about what they have going on inside the windows, I'm just curious as to how they are bypassing the min size limits.

Comment: One option might be to use a JavaScript dialog/modal in the page when the browser/page action is clicked instead of using the built-in popup maybe? Haven't tested yet. <sup>From [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/nJIWEuJpI3Y) topic</sup>